# Is there a free PHP/AJAX file management script with directory synchronization?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script

I want a real easy file management script with a nice clean interface which I can run on my own hosting and password protect.

I also want to be able to sync a folder in it to my computer.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with PHP or webmasters?

Comment: I wasn't quite sure where to place it. I was thinking webmasters as they may know of some good software, cause it can be a way to replace ftp if need be and php because I saw a few that were using php

Comment: Which operating system do you use? (Windows/Mac/*nix/..?)

Comment: CentOS 5.7. But I was hoping for something that uses ajax,php or something which can just be installed as like a web manager no physical daemon running or anything.

Something like this would be cool http://www.filerun.com but they aren't free, nor cheap.

Comment: There are a variety of [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) and [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) clients which meet your requirements for ease of use (only downside: you would need to give users accounts on the system)

Comment: I don't really want a client, I want a web GUI. 

Basically the filemanager would just be a website that is a gui of the folder structures and files on the server, chosen by me.

Think this may clear up a few things people are thinking.

Have a look at this:

http://www.filerun.com/demo

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm quite content with [dirList](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dir-list/). Although old, it works nicely. Be sure to get the download with the upload fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think [AjaxExplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/) has all except file sync, i really believe file synchronization falls outside the domain of a ajax based application , because ajax will be web based and since http is not ideal for communicating with you computer's file system.